# Website receiving wrong domain

Tags: wordpress, dns, web

Im pretty new to serverside and just made my first droplet, so please forgive me if I've missed something obvious here. We have a AWS server currently has multiple websites in different sub-folders.

```
we already point custom domain (www.websitecustom.com) to this server & redirect to www.website1.com/custom (by htaccess) & it works.
www.website1.com
/home/website1/WP core 

wwww.website2.com
/home/website2/WP core
```

But now I really want to remove www.website2.com and use www.websitecustom.com to point to /home/website2. Here what I did:

- Remove the redirect code in htaccess of website1.
- Change all domain name in website 2 database to "www.websitecustom.com"

It did not work, www.websitecustom.com still point to website 1 homepage all day long. Please give me advice. Thanks

UPDATED: It was http & https issue for me. Thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your case, but common mistakes are:

- the redirect was cached. Try a different browser to make sure that is not the case. Especially if it was a 301 redirect, some browsers cache that indefinietely
- make sure your change is deployed.

You can check the redirect path by using `wget` in the console:

```
wget https://www.websitecustom.com --no-check-certificate 2>&1 | grep Location
```